# Excel connector

Tags: integration

I have downloaded the sforce-Connector from the following link

http://code.google.com/p/excel-connector/downloads/detail?name=SForce_Office_Toolkit_MSI.zip

i tried to upload this in Excel add-In. But got error. "not a valid add-In"

Please help me on this.

Regards

sathish.

Comment: Have you followed these instructions https://code.google.com/p/excel-connector/wiki/Install? You may be better off posting your problem at https://code.google.com/p/excel-connector/issues/list (with more detail).

Comment: Keith yes i done the same give in the Link above. Downloaded the SForce_Office_Toolkit_MSI.zip from the link.And tried to add the ZIP to add_in as excel. getting error "SForce_Office_Toolkit_MSI is not a valid addIn"